# не работает парсинг пустая консоль

Tags: python, html, requests, beautiful-soup, lxml

Пытаюсь просто вывести код страницы в консоль. Почему не работает? Программа просто заканчивает работу сразу после включения, ничего не выдав в консоль. Два разных кода попробовал:

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://quotes.toscrape.com/'
response = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'lxml')

print(soup)
```

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://health-diet.ru/table_calorie/?utm_source=leftMenu&utm_medium=table_calorie" 
     
req = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
src = req.text
print(src)
```

Comment: у меня оба кода работают)

Comment: в этом то и дело почему у меня не работает?

Answer (score 0):

Надо было код писать в файле с названием main.py

Comment: А что, по-другому файл с кодом разве нельзя называть? Это какая-то ерунда. А как вы код запускали?

Comment: в пайчарме  запускал